# trigger a click function in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very basic click-function which does some functions:

```
$('#one').click(function() { 
    slider();
    $(this).css({'background-image':'url(img/circle_c.png)'});
    $('#two, #three').css({'background-image':'url(img/circle.png)'});
    $content.cycle(0); 
    return false;  
});
```

now I want to trigger this click function at another click-function. I mean once I press another click-function which currently looks like this:

```
$mario.on('click', this, function() {
    var l = 0,
    row = 8;
    $(this).addClass('active');
    // and some other functions
});
```

the first click-function fires as well. Does anyone of you know how to do this. I guess copy and paste the content of `#one` clickfunction is not nessecary.

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$('#one').trigger('click');
```

So your complete code would looks like this

```
$mario.on('click', this, function() {
    var l = 0,
    row = 8;
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#one').trigger('click'); // < -- trigger click for #one
    // and some other functions
});
```

Comment: or `$('#one').click()`;

Comment: @ClaudioRedi this works fine, but unfortunenately it does not trigger the `$content.cycle()` function in the `#one` click. Don't know why

Comment: @ClaudioRedi nope, nothing. Its `cycle.js` and all functions inside the triggered function do their job, but the cycle not.

Comment: @supersize: I don't see that `$content` is defined inside click handler, maybe someone else is messing up with that global variable?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi no, `$content` works at the first click-function. And as the trigger refers to that it should work. Its global and no issues. But I guess this isnt your point anymore, question is correctly answered.

Answer (score 0):

Break the first click-handling code out into a function:

```
function swapImages() {
  slider();
  $('#one').css({'background-image':'url(img/circle_c.png)'});
  $('#two, #three').css({'background-image':'url(img/circle.png)'});
  $content.cycle(0); 
  return false;  
}
```

And reference it in both places:

```
$('#one').click( swapImages );

$mario.on('click', this, function() {
    var l = 0,
    row = 8;
    $(this).addClass('active');

    swapImages();

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. You can use the [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method.

```
$("#one").trigger('click');
```

Or you can use the [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method with no arguments. Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rxypa/).

```
$("#one").click();
```